# Can Windows 8.1 RT join a domain

Tags: domain, active-directory, windows-8.1, windows-rt

Can Windows 8.1 RT join an Active Directory 2012 domain? I've been looking around and I'm having a hard time determining if they are talking about 8.1 or 8.1 RT but its very unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, according to [the FAQ for Windows 8.1 RT](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-rt-faq), under the question "What's the difference between Windows 8.1 RT and Windows 8.1?":

> Some features **aren't** included in Windows RT 8.1:
>
> - Windows Media Player
> - Windows Media Center
> - HomeGroup creation (you can join an existing HomeGroup but you can't create a new one)
> - The ability to connect to your Windows RT 8.1 PC from another PC using Remote Desktop
> - **Domain join**

Answer (score 5):

The [Windows RT FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-rt-faq) clearly states that joining a domain is *not* available in Windows RT 8.1.